# JQuery Calendar control only appears once when clicking on textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a JQuery calendar which works perfectly on my webpage but only once. After i select the date and i try to click on the textbox  to change the date the calendar doesn't appear.

here is my code 
`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();           
    });
```

`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtDatePicker_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: remove autoPostBack="True" from your code

Comment: thanks your right but i need the auto post back to fire ontextChanged Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i figured it out.
the was because of the AutoPostBack. When using AutoPostBack the is a partial page load so therefore the datepicker did not work. i added the datepicker binding to the pageLoad function and it works perfectly now.....

thanks for all your answers guys

```
 function pageLoad() {
        $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement for showing datepicker is executing only once on `document.ready`. You can bind the `focus` event to open it when `TextBox` gets focus

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
    $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();           


    $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").focus(function () {           
         $(this).datepicker();           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").on('click focus',function(){
      $(this).datepicker();
   }).datepicker();       
});
```

See what is happening in your code you just initialized the datepicker on page load (`doc ready`) event only so if you want to change the date then you have to bind an event of either `focus` or `click`, although both will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="date" placeholder="Choose a date..." value="" />

$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
        altField: selectedDay,
        altFormat: "DD",

    });
```